# Class that inherits from `list` loses type after addition

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm working with a class that inherits from `list`:

```
class MyList(list):
    def func(self):
        print(self)
```

And trying to use some of `list`'s built-in `__add__` method to concatenate two lists:

```
A = MyList([1,2,3])
B = MyList([4,5,6])
C = A + B
```

Now, the type of C will revert to `list`:

```
type(A)
>>>>__main__.MyList

type(C)
>>>>list
```

and as such, the new method `func` is no longer accessible.
I've found that using `__iadd__` behaves as expected:

```
B += A
type(B)
>>>>__main__.MyList
```

Any ideas why this happens, and what can I do to work around that?

Comment: You can "work around" it by adding a `__add__` method that changes the behavior to return a `MyList`.

Comment: As you use `list.__add__` you get a `list` that's normal, Implement `__add__` in your class